# Search PHP Session for a value

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to search this array that is in a session and see if it contains a value. I have posted the code below.

Thanks you.

```
$stack = array ('hello', 'world', 'where', 'are', 'money', 'chicken', 'run');

$_SESSION['user'] = $stack;
 if($_SESSION['user'] does not contain('myname')){
     echo 'no name';
   }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here.  Are you just trying to determine if an array contains a specific value?  This question isn't related to the session, it just happens that your array is stored in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function

> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

example:

```
if(!in_array('myname', $_SESSION['user']))
{
    //code to be executed if 'myname' is not in the array
}

else
{
    //code to be executed if 'myname' is in the array
}
```

Also, might i suggest you just do it like this?

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user'] = array('hello', 'world', 'where', 'are', 'money', 'chicken', 'run');  

if(!in_array('myname', $_SESSION['user']))
{
    //code to be executed if 'myname' is not in the array
}

else
{
    //code to be executed if 'myname' is in the array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to check that the session variable exists or you'll throw an error, then you can check for the string in the variable with the in_array function.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])):
echo(in_array('my_name', $_SESSION['user']));
else:
echo false;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_array('myvalue', $_SESSION['user'])){
    // $_SESSION['user'] contains 'myvalue'
} else {
   // $_SESSION['user'] does not contain 'myvalue'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check if a value exists in an array.

Alternatively, you could loop through $_SESSION['user'] to check if value exists in an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in_array function

```
$stack = array ('hello', 'world', 'where', 'are', 'money', 'chicken', 'run');

if (!in_array($_SESSION['user'], $stack)) {

    echo 'no name';
}
```